# Failure to release force register in verilog

Tags: memory-management, verilog

I having an issue with my forcing, I was unable to release the force that i had set for my register. Is release code I used was wrongly coded?

The force coding in my test bench:
*note ram is a reg*

```
initial begin
#41     force   test.P2.ram[001][1] = 'b0;
#5      release test.P2.ram[001][1];
end
```

but from the results I get is this 
[image]

Which it should release the value from 'b0 but it don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Verilog and SystemVerilog LRMs do not allow a `force` on bit-selects of a packed array(vector). Some tools have been enhanced to allow this, but I'm guessing they did not enhance `release` at the same time. Try

```
 release test.P2.ram[001];
```

I would also try explicitly setting that bit to 1'b1 after the release to make sure it's not a coincidence that the bit remains 0.

Comment: still the same, guess the explanation goes to unable to release a forced packed array.

Comment: You should report this to the tool vendor. force/release need to work with variables of the same data type. You are going to need to find another way of corrupting your `ram`.